# How to dynamically add more width inside a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, width

I've created a timeline with jQuery UI. To my problem: If I add more years with images and text, how to dynamically add more space inside that div? In this case: `#timline`. The problem occurs when I'm adding more years, I need to change the width inside timeline. It is set to more than 3000px. How can I prevent this? Heres a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/suhge2or/) on the case

HTML:

```
<div id="timeline-container">
    <div id="timeline-header">
        <h1>Journey</h1>
        <h2>Show years</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="slider"></div>
    <ul id="timeline">
        <li class="element">
            <img src="img/ikon_lampa_1.png" alt="Allra" />
            <ul>
                <li class="text">
                    <h3>2008</h3><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore.</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="element down">
            <img src="img/ikon_tumme_upp_3.png" alt="Allra" />
            <ul>
                <li class="text">
                    <h3>2009</h3><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore.</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="element">
            <img src="img/ikon_folk_3.png" alt="Allra" />
            <ul>
                <li class="text">
                    <h3>2010</h3><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore.</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="element down">
            <img src="img/ikon_fondforsiktig_4.png" alt="Allra" />
            <ul>
                <li class="text">
                    <h3>2011</h3><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="element">
            <img src="img/ikon_ballong_1.png" alt="Allra" />
            <ul>
                <li class="text">
                    <h3>2012</h3><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="element down">
            <img src="img/ikon_allralogga_2.png" alt="Allra" />
            <ul>
                <li class="text">
                    <h3>2013</h3><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="element">
            <img src="img/ikon_pekare_3.png" alt="Allra" />
            <ul>
                <li class="text">
                    <h3>2014</h3><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: white;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
#timeline-container {
    width: 100%;
    background: #fef7e7;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 40px auto;
}
#timeline-header {
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline;
    top: 35px;
    left: 50%;
}
#timeline-header h1 {
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 16pt;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
#timeline-header h2 {
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 8pt;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#slider {
    z-index: 100;
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 200px;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 10px;
}
.ui-slider {
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    position: relative;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 20px 0;
    background-color: #87c80a;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #39a6dd, #87c80a);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 0, from(#39a6dd), to(#87c80a));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #39a6dd, #87c80a);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #39a6dd, #87c80a);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #39a6dd, #87c80a);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff39a6dd', endColorstr='#ff87c80a', GradientType=1);
}
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    top: -10px;
    margin-left: -15px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 0;
    background: #505759;
}
#timeline {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 3650px;
    max-width: auto;
    height: 480px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.element {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 400px;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    left: 400px;
    float: left;
}
.down {
    margin-top: 70px;
}
.element > ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
}
.element li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.element img {
    width: 160px;
}
ul li .text {
    width: 260px;
    text-align: center;
    text-indent: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -35px;
}
ul li .text h3 {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 43px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-weight: bold;
}
ul li .text span {
    font-size: 10pt;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(function () {
    var scrollPane = $("#timeline-container"),
        scrollContent = $("#timeline");

    var scrollbar = $("#slider").slider({
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            if (scrollContent.width() > scrollPane.width()) {
                scrollContent.css("margin-left", Math.round(
                ui.value / 100 * (scrollPane.width() - scrollContent.width())) + "px");
            } else {
                scrollContent.css("margin-left", 0, "left", 0);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `divs` expand themselves to fit their content by default. Just don't define a `width` for them.

Comment: I tried that, but then the li-elements ends up in a vertical line instead of horizontal...

Comment: Set the `lis` `display` to `inline`.

Comment: I've also tried that, didn't help me in this case... If you manage to do so, please share a working fiddle

Comment: Could you clarify please?  I don't see any dynamic adding code in the fiddle. Are you trying to have the size of one div match the size of another? If so, could you state which ones specifically. I would imagine when you add a new element, find the width with javascript and set the width value to the other element.

Comment: Oh, I see your point. Okay: inside the ul #timeline I want the width to expand or scale down depending how many li-elements I have inside the #timeline. As you can see, I have 2008, 2009, 2010 and so on. If I want to add 2015, how can I make the ul #timeline to expand?

Comment: These two don't work together: `position: absolute;` and `display: inline;`

Comment: Oh, I changed that. Probably old CSS that came along...

Comment: you can calculate the width of the li your adding and modify the ul width in consequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
#timeline {
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: auto;
  height: 480px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

and also add display property for firefox like 
display: -moz-inline-box; 
or something like that i believe

Comment: That worked! But for some reason 2014 doesn't show. Why is that? Is it because I've set "left" on .element class?

Comment: i guess so. Try using margin-left instead

Comment: or better use padding on parent element

Comment: Thank you! This really came along!

Comment: For some reason the jQuery UI slider doesn't work in Mozilla and IE because of display: -webkit-inline-box, even if I've added -moz-inline-box...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63235/discussion-between-rubinen-and-xottabych007).